# I cannot get the p-value from spearman's Correlation in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, correlation

I am calculating a Spearman's correlation between two bands of an image collection dataset, but when I use the function to get it, it only outputs the correlation coefficients, but not the p-value. When I use Pearson's correlation, it works perfectly.

this is an example (I am working with anomalies, but it is the same with the p-value in Spearman's correlation):

```
var geometry = 
/* color: #d63000 */
/* displayProperties: [
  {
    "type": "rectangle"
  }
] */
ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-76.65515847588877, 4.901043955695389],
      [-76.65515847588877, 3.876848364980054],
      [-75.50159402276377, 3.876848364980054],
      [-75.50159402276377, 4.901043955695389]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2000-12-01', '2022-08-01'))
              .select(['vpd', 'pdsi'])
              .map(function(image) {return image.clip(geometry)})
              .map(function(image) {
                return image
                  .round()
                  .divide(ee.Number(10))
                  .set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
              });

var Pearsons_correlation = dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation());
var Spearmans_correlation = dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.spearmansCorrelation());

Map.addLayer(Pearsons_correlation, {}, 'Pearsons_Correlation');
Map.addLayer(Pearsons_correlation.select('p-value'), {}, 'Pearsons p-values');

Map.addLayer(Spearmans_correlation, {}, 'Spearmans_Correlation');
Map.addLayer(Spearmans_correlation.select('p-value'), {}, 'Spearmans p-values');
```

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, thanks for the answer, I did it. it is an example because my code is longer, but I get the same problem with the p-values in Spearman's correlation